# How to obtain this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

> Hi, I have to find this expression

$$[(r-M)\partial_r + \mu\partial_\mu](\mu_2+\mu_3)=2-\frac{(r-M)^2}{\Delta}-\frac{2rM}{\rho^2}$$

> from this one

$$0=2[(r-M)\partial_r + \mu\partial_\mu](\mu_2 + \mu_3)-\frac{1}{\chi^2}[\Delta\partial_r\chi\partial_r\textit{Y}-\delta\partial_\mu\chi\partial_\mu\textit{Y}]+3\frac{M^2-a^2}{\Delta}-\frac{1}{\delta}$$

> with

$$\Delta=r^2+a^2-2rM$$

$$\rho^2=r^2+a^2\mu^2$$

$$\delta=1-\mu^2$$

$$\Sigma^2=(r^2+a^2)^2-a^2\Delta\delta$$

$$\frac{1}{\chi^2}=\frac{\delta\Sigma^4}{\rho^4\Delta}$$

$$\partial_r\chi=\frac{(r-M)\rho^2-(\sqrt{\Delta}+a\sqrt{\delta})2r\sqrt{\Delta}}{\sqrt{\Delta\delta}[r^2+a^2+a\sqrt{\Delta\delta}]^2}$$

$$\partial_r\textit{Y}=\frac{(r-M)\rho^2-(\sqrt{\Delta}-a\sqrt{\delta})2r\sqrt{\Delta}}{\sqrt{\Delta\delta}[r^2+a^2-a\sqrt{\Delta\delta}]^2}$$

$$\partial_\mu\chi=\frac{\mu\sqrt{\Delta}[r^2+a^2+a^2\delta+2a\sqrt{\Delta\delta}]}{\delta^{\frac{3}{2}}[r^2+a^2+a\sqrt{\Delta\delta}]^2}$$

$$\partial_\mu\textit{Y}=\frac{\mu\sqrt{\Delta}[r^2+a^2+a^2\delta-2a\sqrt{\Delta\delta}]}{\delta^{\frac{3}{2}}[r^2+a^2-a\sqrt{\Delta\delta}]^2}$$

I tried many times without success

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... I took a shot at entering this into *Mathematica*, but I didn't get the desired equality; there's no telling how many typos I made, though. ... Please edit your question to say something about the context of all this. How did these terms arise? What makes you think that the stated equality is actually true? Are you sure there are no typos of your own? (Might the "$u$" in your definition of $\rho$ actually be a "$\mu$"?) ... Such info may motivate answerers; moreover, we might be able to double-check your work and/or find alternative paths to the answer. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry there's a typo, the result should be $$[(r-M)\partial_r + \mu\partial_\mu](\mu_2+\mu_3)=2-\frac{(r-M)^2}{\Delta}-\frac{2rM}{\rho^2}$$, it's from the mathematical theory of black holes from chandrasekhar, it's related to the kerr metric

Comment: *"Sorry there's a typo"* ... Be sure to edit the correction into the question body; comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden. ... Also, since the left-hand side of the first equation appears in the second, you could de-clutter a bit by asking to show that $$\frac1{\chi^2}[\Delta\partial_r\chi\partial_rY-\delta\partial_\mu\chi\partial_\mu Y]-3\frac{M^2-a^2}\Delta+\frac{1}{\delta}$$ reduces to $$2-\frac{(r-M)^2}\Delta-\frac{2rM}{\rho^2}$$

Comment: Is it safe to assume every individual character is a standalone symbol, and the expression doesn't contain some unexplained operator?

Comment: Yes, there's no operator

Comment: Assuming $u$ is a typo for $\mu$ (or vice-versa), I find that
$$\frac1{X^2}[\Delta X_r Y_r - \delta X_m Y_m]-\frac3\Delta(M^2-a^2)+\frac1\delta\quad=\quad 2 + \frac2\Delta(a^2 - M^2) - \frac{4 r M}{\rho^2}$$ Manipulating this into the right-hand side of the target equation would seem to require an additional relation among the parameters.

Comment: Sorry for the typos, i edited it

Comment: @Kahler272: Thanks to the new edits, one can now show:
$$\frac1{X^2}[\Delta X_r Y_r - \delta X_m Y_m]-\frac3\Delta(M^2-a^2)+\frac1\delta\quad=\quad 2\left( 2 - \frac1\Delta(r-M)^2 - \frac{2 r M}{\rho^2} \right) \qquad (\star)$$ as desired. ... Were your own previous efforts based on the erroneous form? That is, have you tried working with the corrected version? (Knowing the correct form $(\star)$, "all you have to do" is subtract one side of the equation from the other, expand like crazy, and show that everything cancels. It's tedious, but do-able.)

Comment: Yes i tried with the correct form but it's a mess

Comment: Did you find the correct result tho?